# Why isn't the args parameter used in ActionController::Instrumentation::render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I am new to Ruby and to Rails, and am trying to understand fully what I'm reading.

I am looking at some of the Rails source code, in this case `action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb`.

```
def render(*args)
  render_output = nil
  self.view_runtime = cleanup_view_runtime do
    Benchmark.ms { render_output = super }
  end
  render_output
end
```

I understand that `*args` is using the splat operator to collect the arguments together into an array. But after that, it stops making much sense to me.

I can't fathom why `render_output` is set to nil before being reassigned to equal `super` and then called with no arguments. I gather that some speedtest is being done, but coming from other languages I'd expect this to just be something more like `Benchmark.ms(render_output)` or perhaps `Benchmark.start` followed by `render_output` followed by `Benchmark.end`. I'm having a hard time following the way it works here.

But more importantly, I don't really follow why `args` isn't used again. Why bother defining a param that isn't used? And I mean, clearly it is getting used-- I just don't see how. There's some hidden mechanism here that I haven't learned about yet.

Comment: `*args` is used. When you call `super` without parentheses and without arguments then it implicitly calls `super` with the same arguments that were passed to the current method. That means in this case `super` behaves as if `super(*args)` was called.

Comment: Ah ha, there's the hidden mechanism to which I referred! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it is important to note how `super` works, because in some cases it passes implicitly arguments and you might not expect that.

When you have method like

```
def method(argument)
  super
end
```

then super is calling the overridden implementation of `method` implicitly with the exact same arguments as the current method was called. That means in this example super will actually call `super(argument)`.

Of course, you can still define a method call that explicitly sends other arguments to the original implementation, like in this example:

```
def method(argument)
  super(argument + 1)
end
```

Another important edge-case is when you want to explicitly call super without any arguments although the current method was called with arguments then you need to be very explicit like this

```
def method(argument)
  super()                      # note the empty parentheses
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to describe you what I think this code does.

`*args*`

> is using the splat operator to collect the arguments together into an array

that is totally correct, however they don't use it, and if you will go to [master](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb#L43) branch, they just changed it to `*`. Asking why it is defined and not used, I think that's question about bad design. They should have called it `_args` or at least like it is now just single splat `*`.

`render_output` is set to nil because of scopes, it has to be explicitly defined out block, lambda, proc in order to store value in it, otherwise its visibility will be locked only to those lambda, proc, block execution. Refer to [this article](https://jacopretorius.net/2012/01/block-variable-scope-in-ruby.html)

`Benchmark.start`. Blocks are great ruby construction. You are totally correct that speedtest is done, we can see it is just decorator for `benchmark` library.
[source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a750b0cf8fe362ef762f34972e2d1ec302795174/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb#L13).
You are wondering why we cannot just pass it as `Benchmark.ms(render_output)`, that's because what will be given to benchmark `ms` function? It will be given result, like `<div> my html </div`. And how we can measure this string result - no how. That's why we calling super right in this block, we want to access parent class function and wrap it inside block, so we are not calling it, we just construct it, and it will be called inside `benchmark` lib, and measured execution like

```rb
class Benchmark
  ...
  def realtime # :yield:
    r0 = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
    yield
    Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC) - r0
  end
  ...
end
```

So here we can count realtime of function execution, this is the code from [original library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-realtime)

Comment: As @spickerman pointed out in his comment and subsequently in his post your statement that `args` is not used or is bad design is inaccurate. The call to `super` without parents implicitly passes all arguments (`args` in this case) that were passed to the calling method

Comment: @engineersmnky yes.
and what @spickermann that is totally correct, I missed this part about `super` in my answer. The why I called it bad design, because `args` is not used in this method, they should indicate this, like simple splat or `_args`. the way they passed to parent class doesn't affect the fact they are unused in this method.

Comment: in rubocop 0.74+ you will have warning about args argument.
`def initialize(*args)` => Lint/UnusedMethodArgument: Unused method argument - args. If it's necessary, use _ or _args as an argument name to indicate that it won't be used. You can also write as initialize(*) if you want the method to accept any arguments but don't care about them